# Add JSON Objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, variables

So I'm pulling some JSON with AngularJS using this

```
$http.get('/balance').then(function (response) {
  $scope.balance = response.data;
});
```

and the `response.data` is this

```
{
  "pending": [{
    "amount": 16,
    "currency": "usd"
  }],
  "available": [{
    "amount": 20,
    "currency": "usd"
  }],
  "livemode": false,
  "object": "balance"
}
```

How do I add the two "amounts" together and set them equal to a variable in Angular? So for this one the variable should be set to `16+20`?

Comment: In pending array and available array has a length of 0, is it fixed or can grow?

Comment: @user3161730, parse your JSON into JS dictionary, `parseInt()` amounts, and add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.newProp = response.data.pending[0].amount + response.data.available[0].amount;`